# OnItemSelectedIndexChange hide or remove selected DropDownList item

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am sure this has been done but cannot seem to find a resolution anywhere, or figure it out at this late hour.

I have two DropDownLists:

`ddConvertFrom`
`ddConvertTo`

`OnItemSelectedIndexChange` for either of the DropDownLists, I want to remove/hide the selected value from the other DropDownList.

So far I have tried this:

```
protected void ddConvertTo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem li in ddConvertTo.Items)
    {
        if (ddConvertFrom.SelectedItem.Text == li.Text)
        {
            ddConvertTo.Items.Remove(ddConvertTo.Items.FindByValue(ddConvertFrom.SelectedItem.Text));
        }

    }
}
```

A) Why does the above not work?

B) Is there a more efficient way of doing this above?

Comment: well, if i were you i dont use server side controllers and post-backs for that, i use ajax and jquery

Comment: Yeah I think that is probably the best route now, but would still like to see solution above work.

Comment: just remove item and redatabind to dropdown.

Comment: Thats what I am doing aint it?  `ddConvertTo.Items.Remove(ddConvertTo.Items.FindByValue(ddConvertFrom.SelectedItem.Text));` whats wrong there?

Comment: I have AutoPostBack set to true

Comment: ahh i get wrong your question sorry, answer is below

Comment: Are your drop down option texts and values identical?  I ask because you are trying to find (by value) the item in ddConvertTo by searching on the selected ddConvertFrom item's text value.

Comment: Yes they are the same at this point in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, be sure autopostbacks are true then check this.

```
    protected void ddConvertTo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
     foreach (ListItem li in ddConvertTo.Items)
     {
        if (ddConvertFrom.SelectedItem.Text == li.Text)
        {

             ddConvertTo.Items.Remove(ddConvertTo.Items.FindByText(ddConvertFrom.SelectedItem.Text));
             break;

        }

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the item from the collection prior to binding rather than try to remove it afterwards.

Comment: Ahh the binding wasn't the item causing the issue here but the code above still fails. Also good spot that would of caused me problems.